# Why owners of files and folders can modify it's contents if they don't have permissions on the parent directory?

Tags: permissions, ownership

An example of my question would be the `/home` directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Jan 29 23:44 home/
```

So, the owner of `/home` is `root`.

But I'm the owner of my personal home folder:

```
drwx--x--- 85 teo     teo      4096 Jan 30 16:22 teo/
```

Why is my user able to modify things under `teo/` folder if the `/home` is owned by the `root`?
I mean, modifications on my personal folder are also modifications in the `/home` folder, because it is a subfolder of `/home`, and I'm not in the `root` group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix, there are files and directories (and some weird "files" like pipes and devices, but permissions on them work just like plain files), and symbolic links (in essence, files containing the name of the file they point to). A directory is just a list of file names and references to the corresponding physical files. This way you can have the same file appearing under different names, or under the same (or another) name in different directories.

There are three basic permissions on filessystem objects: r(ead), w(rite) and e(x)ecute. For regular files, read means to be able to read it's contents (e.g. copy it, view it, ...), write means to be able to modify it's contents (overwrite, add stuff at the end, truncate to length zero; note that this is independent of reading, you can have a file you can modify but not read), execute means running it as a program. For directories, read means listing it's contents (file names), writing means modifying (adding/deleting files), execution means using the directory to get at the files themselves (if you have r but not x on the directory, you can see the file names, but not get at them). Symbolic link's permissions are irrelevant, just take them as mentioned above: A short file containing the file name pointed to, and the contents is processed normally. Yes, quite orthogonal (independent).

The system classifies permissions into three groups: The owner, the group the object belongs to, and everybody else. Each user belongs to one (or more) groups. When checking if an operation is allowed, first check if you are the owner, if so, the owner permissions rule; if you aren't the owner but belong to the group, group permissions are considered; otherwise, other permissions are checked.

True, it allows rather nonsensical combinations of permissions. But it is a simple model, and some day you'll find use for some "nonsense" combination.

The owner of some object has the power to change permissions at will.

Answer (score 0):

Because permission to change the mode of a file is with the owning user of the file.

Because being able to change your own files and directories is a good idea.

Because it does not change the parent directory: The parent directory contains the names of child files (and directories). The mode (including permission is part of the file (not part of the containing directory). You can see this if you create a hard link, from two directories.